# Sitecore link management between two separate instances of the same website while upgrade

Tags: hyperlink, sitecore

We have a Sitecore 6.5 Webforms solution with huge amount of legacy code, which we want completely rewrite to Sitecore 8.1 MVC. The project is very big and it will take around one year to have everything up and running in the new build, so we decided to maintain both systems in the same time and switch off the old website piece by piece while we are making progress with the new one.

We are going to have separate servers for each Sitecore instance and handle URLs between the old/new version using load balancer. We want to keep all existing URLs as they are now. We are going to migrate the existing content 1:1 to the new system, but it is possible that we will have new pages in the new install.

I have a question regarding the link management when a content editor wants to point from the old system to the new system. For example when we want to add hyperlink inside rich text editor which points from old system to the new page in the new one (not existing in the old system) - if you try to insert internal link you do not have access to the new content tree, moreover in links to existing items you have a guid:

```
<a href="~/link.aspx?_id=095E6A07668C4DA99B968EF5A90CE4CB&amp;_z=z">Link text</a>
```

which obviously will change in the new version and will not work properly. Do you know any good way to handle that?

I know that it is possible to use external links between both systems but this approach has a very poor user experience and takes more time if you want to add a few links, so we are looking for better solution to make content editors life easier.

Comment: How are you going to be handling your content editing? Will editors be working in 2 separate CMS systems (old and new)? What about going forward, how will you be syncing content between both the systems? I would asked this question on the [Community Forums](https://community.sitecore.net/), any answer here would be opinion based imo,

Comment: We divided the website into a few sections for different audiences. We are going to rewrite one of them, deploy and switch off the old one. My question was about links from the old website parts (that are still in use) to the new part because the client want to be able to have cross-platform links between different audiences. We want to write a script to move all content between systems and we will be doing that before going live with new section. After that content editors should work on new system only for this part of the website and in the meantime still maintain the rest of the old system

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do, but without the content being in both systems, it will not be able to resolve the guid based links. Only alternative is to use "external link" as you have suggested but that means that links will not be automatically updated if content is moved for example.

Comment: My suggestion would be to upgrade the current solution to 8.1 and update the code base alongside. You can run WebForms and MVC in the same solution as long as you don't mix component types in a single request. That way you are working from a single Sitecore instance.

Comment: We considered having both versions in one solution but this approach is not recommended by Sitecore. The client decided that they want to build a new version from scratch because the legacy code is terrible - the only good thing that we can say about the legacy code is that it has been written in C# ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.ExpandDynamicLinks() method to transform dynamic links into friendly URLs.

You can use the Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.ExpandDynamicLinks() method to transform dynamic links in Rich Text Editor (RTE) fields, including both content and media links, to friendly
URLs. 
For example, to transform dynamic links in the Text field in the

```
    /Sitecore/Content/Home
```

item in the Master database:

```
 Sitecore.Data.Database master = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");
 Sitecore.Data.Items.Item home = master.GetItem("/sitecore/content/home");
 string containsDynamicLinks = home.Fields["text"].Value;
 string containsFriendlyLinks = Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.ExpandDynamicLinks(containsDynamicLinks, Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.Rendering.SiteResolving);
string finalMarkup =System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(containsFriendlyLinks,"([^/])~/media", "$1/~/media");
```

Please check below on chapter 5.4    https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/64/content_api_cookbook_sc64_and_later-a4.pdf

Comment: I don't think the question is about expanding links, but managing links between (essentially) 2 separate Sitecore instances. This will not help with that, since the item may not exist in this instance and therefore expandsion will fail.

Comment: you are right, if I read one more time I can say the idea from the question is bad, they need to sync the environments not to map from one to other one.

Comment: Didn't someone have a blog post recently where they made a new Sitecore site that reached into an old instance, for urls, for rewriting old to new? Its was a overweight 301 redirect engine. But there was so many links and the site had to be re-architected. If we can find that article, that might help.

Comment: @dnstommy Way ahead of you, that was me :p https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2015/01/19/redirecting-urls-after-major-content-restructure-in-sitecore/

Comment: Bam. Winning! That might help her.